# How connect to DB PosgreSQL in pgAdmin4 with port 84?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Install DB Server PosgreSQL 
postgresql-9.6.1-1-windows-x64.

After Install I change number standard port to 84.
In postgresql.conf

```
port = 84               # 5433 (change requires restart)
```

I restarted service and new port working.

After I try to connected DB Server by pgAdmin4.

But when I change Connection Port pgAdmin4 wrote ERROR

[image]

Can I connected to DB with port less 1024?

Comment: why you take 2 digit port number? it must be greater than 1024.

Comment: "* I change number standard port to 84" - why would you do that? What is the reason behind that?

Comment: I have a small test lab. It has some of the database. test lab allows podklchyuchatsya to them from outside. But the router has a limit on the number of individual records NAT port. Therefore, the connection ports begin with 82.

Comment: You could file a bug to pgAdmin. This error should be a mere warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your port number must be greater than 1024, as message printed on your screen.
Less than 1024 given error in pgadmin.

Comment: I want to conect DB with 84 number port. pgAdmin4 do not give me such an opportunity?

Comment: Never give this opportunity because port number must be greater than 1024

Answer (score 3):

You may want to consider manipulating the SQLite DB backing pgAdmin 4, stored e.g. at AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin\pgadmin4.db.

Create your server in pgAdmin with a port > 1024, then via SQLite remove the constraint in the server table on the port column (or change it from "port > 1024..." to "port > 1..."), and then change the value of the port column on the corresponding server line.

Of course, that's a hack and will probably be overridden when you install pgAdmin updates.

Comment: I couldn't find any information about how to change the actual PgAdmin configuration other than through the UI but your hint at the SQLite db saved my day. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2):

There is a very good reason this port restriction should be removed.  When using a Platform As A Service (PAAS) that creates endpoints based on services, it is typical to create the service on port 80 or 443 regardless of what is behind the URL.  Since this is just a host name, there is no reason why this should be blocked.  The landscape is different then the data center level as these services could be spun up at any time.  This requirement is arbitrary.